# Why is thunder and lightning rare, even though it rains frequently?

Tags: rainfall, lightning, thunderstorm, rain

Why in some places (for example Dublin, Ireland) the thunder and lightning is such a rare thing even though it rains so frequently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rain in a climate such as Ireland is most often stratiform. That is, it is created when moist air is lifted by a front, or by divergence in the upper troposphere. Thunderstorms involve buoyant air, which rises on its own due to its being warmer than its surroundings. Typically solar radiation is involved in heating the surface such that the air near it warms and becomes buoyant. That is more common in lower latitudes and locations that are typically sunny.

Comment: Good short and simple meteorologically sound answer jake! I can definitely appreciate that, as my answers usually are annoyingly long. The only thing I'd add is thunderstorms can indeed commonly be found from dynamically-generated lift as well... but the key is they need rapid ascent, which is heavily dependent upon the vertical temperature profile. Places in some regimes, such as those dominated by cool oceans, tend to have less instability in lifted parcels (whether dynamic or thermal lifted). But solid answer, and welcome, hope you'll find this a useful place to contribute for many years!

Comment: Thanks! I probably would have gotten more long winded if I hadn't been using my phone 

Comment: You managed that without 15 autocorrect errors?  I am sure I have fixed them all and then still find a dozen.  So even better.  Once again, welcome, encouraging stuff :-)